# What is making JS not run on IE9 but ok on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm learning JS and working on simple codes to practice. When testing basic code (one of the simplest examples is below), IE9 doesn't make it run while Firefox does it no problem. 
I've followed the configuration guidelines in IE9>tools>internet options>security to enable running of scripts, to no avail. Initially I thought it was my JS/jQuery code, but to troubleshoot I tried even the simplest JS code, which is just ignored. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div { color:blue; }
        span { color:red; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        The values stored were
        <span></span>
        and
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("div").data("test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
        $("span:first").text($("div").data("test").first);
        $("span:last").text($("div").data("test").last);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You set a "data" element named "beauty", and then you try to fetch one named "test".  I don't see how you expect that code to do anything.

Comment: Also you should be seeing errors in the console. Have you checked that? You should always have the debug console up when diagnosing JavaScript problems; it's the first thing to check in fact.

Comment: Finally, you needlessly waste the time of people trying to help you out when you post inaccurate questions.

Comment: Your corrected code works just fine in IE9: http://jsbin.com/ewewol/1, with no special "configuration" of IE required at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").data("beauty", { first: 16, last: "beast" });
$("span:first").text($("div").data("test").first);
$("span:last").text($("div").data("test").last);
```

It is easier than it looks. You just have to change `beauty` with `test`, because you assigned data to *beauty* property and you are trying to retrieve it using `test`.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyzrg/)

Now your code will look like:

```
$("div").data("test", { first: 16, last: "beast" });
$("span:first").text($("div").data("test").first);
$("span:last").text($("div").data("test").last);
```

Comment: This is perfectly true, but doesn't fit the symptom described (that code working on Firefox doesn't work on IE9). This is probably just an error in the question.

Comment: I'd like to know if this code works on every browser. If it doesn't, I'll try to find the right(?) answer to the question. The strange thing is that I can't imagine how jQuery, that is written to be cross-browser, could work on FF and not on IE9(which is not so buggy as the others are)!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well from what's posted in the question, it's not clear how this code could possibly have run without incident in Firefox. There's no `data-test` attribute on the `<div>`, so in Firefox you'd get an "undefined" exception. *edit* oh well the edit clarifies things, though now of course the posted code in the question should work just fine in IE9.

Comment: @Pointy: And in fact, it does. :-)

Comment: @LightStyle: Yes, that code (which is what the OP now has in their question as well, so it was indeed just an error asking the question) works in any browser jQuery supports. (Including IE9.) This answer doesn't answer the question. (And I suspect no answer *can* answer the question, I think the OP's just confused. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You saved the data under the key "beauty" but are trying to retrieve data with the key "test", which will return "undefined".

Change "test" to "beauty" and it should work.

```
$(function(){
    $("div").data("beauty", { first: 16, last: "beast" });
    $("span:first").text($("div").data("beauty").first);
    $("span:last").text($("div").data("beauty").last);
});
```

EDIT: 
@PabloFernandez When you open the page in IE, there may be a yellow bar at the bottom that says "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" with a button that says "Allow Blocked Content".  Click the "Allow Blocked Content" button before it disappears and your code should run just fine.

Comment: This is perfectly true, but doesn't fit the symptom described (that code working on Firefox doesn't work on IE9). This is probably just an error in the question.

Comment: Fair point T.J., but after making my suggested changes the code runs fine on IE9 on my machine, as well as Chrome and Firefox.  My answer is based on my results and the code in the OP as it was stated.

Comment: @ Ryan: As I suspected, the OP has now corrected their question. This wasn't the problem. (The question probabyl *can't* be answered, I think the OP's just confused and mis-reporting what they're seeing...)

Comment: thanks everyone. I'm finding my knowledge level to be too low for this forum. With the edited code, I still can't make it work on IE9, for what I believe must be some security/config reason that I can't find. Need to go back and learn a bit more and avoid asking questions which may confuse the folks I'm asking for help. Humble apologies.

Comment: @PabloFernandez When you open the page in IE, there may be a yellow bar at the bottom that says "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" with a button that says "Allow Blocked Content".  Click the "Allow Blocked Content" button before it disappears and your code should run just fine.